# Compiler error when overriding Page_PreInit

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, webforms, master-pages

I am trying to override the `Page_PreInit` function inside my class `_Default` which inherits from `Page`. However, when I try to compile I get the following error:

> '_Default.Page_PreInit(object, System.EventArgs)': no suitable method found to override

Here is my code:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected override void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Todo:
        // The _Default class overrides the Page_PreInit method and sets the value
        //  of the MasterPageFile property to the current value in the 
        //  selectedLayout session variable.

        MasterPageFile = Master.Session["selectedLayout"];
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Page` class declares a public event named [`PreInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) and a protected virtual method named [`OnPreInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.onpreinit.aspx) (which just raises the `PreInit` event). So you have two options.

**Option 1 (recommended):** Override `OnPreInit`:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    // Set the master page here...

    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Call `base.OnPreInit(e)` so that the page raises the `PreInit` event as usual.

**Option 2:** Create a method named `Page_PreInit`. ASP.NET will automatically bind this method to the `PreInit` event as long as you don't set `AutoEventWireup` to `False` in the `@Page` directive or in Web.config.

```
private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set the master page here...
}
```

If you choose this option, don't call `base.OnPreInit`, or else you will end up with an infinite recursion.

Comment: oh ok that makes sense, thanks!

still an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 

here: 
MasterPageFile = Master.Session["selectedLayout"];

Comment: Try `this.Session` instead of `Master.Session`.

Comment: this.session comes up with : cannot apply [] to an expression type 'method group'

Comment: `MasterPageFile = (string)Session["selectedLayout"];`

Comment: You have a method named `Session` in your page that's conflicting with the `Page.Session` property. Either rename your method to something other than `Session`, or use `MasterPageFile = (string)base.Session["selectedLayout"];`

Comment: I wish I could figure this one out, it is very frustrating. Now I get the error: "Content controls are allowed only in content page that references a master page"

Comment: I think the original question about `PreInit` has been resolved. Could you please put a checkmark next to this answer and then post a new question about the error?